# Kth element mod k in geometric sequence ax+b

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider a geometric sequence ax+b(for example 10x+9, the elements are 9,99,999,9999,...) I was wondering if there is a formula to calculate the kth element of the sequence modulo n?

Comment: The elements of $10x+9$ are $9,19,29,39,\ldots$. and not $9,99,999,\ldots.$.

Comment: And what you've described in the formula is an arithmetic series, not a geometric series ...

Comment: No. Actually I meant f[i]=10x+9|x=f[i-1] so we have 10(10(10*0+9)+9)+9)...